# MongoDB findOne with regex (security flaw?)

Tags: regex, security, mongodb

Before i insert the email into the database -> i validate the adress with

```
if (filter_var($emailAdress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
....
}
```

.. but is this maybe a security flaw?

```
$userAccObj = $db->user->findOne( array('email' => array('$regex' => '^'.$emailAdress.'$', '$options' => 'i') ));
```

Schould i do this? or is it not necessary?

```
$emailAdress= preg_replace("/\@/", '\@', $emailAdress);
$emailAdress= preg_replace("/\-/", '\-', $emailAdress);
$emailAdress= preg_replace("/\./", '\.', $emailAdress);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (filter_var($emailAdress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Is a good way to vlaidate an email address in PHP, however, it does use regexes but so far, those have proven to be the best.

```
$userAccObj = $db->user->findOne( array('email' => array('$regex' => '^'.$emailAdress.'$', '$options' => 'i') ));
```

The only real problem with that is the `.` which is a special character which will effect how the regex works, but do you really need to do a regex here? You have checked it is a full email address as such you just need to check for where that exact email address exists (or better yet make a unique index on the field).

As I such I think you can take out the regex and do an exact match.

Comment: i use regex to fix the userinput .. for example -> MYemailAdress@mail.com does not match myemailadress@mail.com in the database. So, when i replace the . with \. -> is everything safe? Right?

Comment: @user2306309 yeah but so not index friendly, that will not use an index. Best thing is to normalise the field to all lower case and then take input and normalise that to lower case

Comment: That was my first idea. Emailadesses can be stored lower case, right. But what do i with the usernames? For example the name: iAmPro ... i dont want to lower case this name :/

Comment: @user2306309 Most sties, including this one store two usernames, one of the display and one of the normalised, I suggest doing that

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me ;) ... Thank you very much!